# Laravel-Mix: Different output path for development and production build (by the example of css)

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

All we see in `webpack.mix` when after crafting the application is below:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I know how to run development and production build, but don't know how to customize it. In this question, we consider the example about compiling `sass` to `css` in different path depending on build type, however I suppose working with `es6` and `pug` building will be similar.

**Project structure**:

public

css-prod

resources

assets

sass

css-dev

I want:

- **Development executing**: files from `resources/assets/sass` compile `resources/assets/css-dev`, no uglification, no concatenation.
- **Production executing**: files from `resources/assets/sass` compile to `resources/assets/css-prod`, uglify and concatenate.

Where I should to define these settings?

Answer (score 8):

This can be done in **webpack.mix.js**:

```
...
if (mix.inProduction()) {
  jsOutputDir = '/path/to/production';
  cssOutputDir = '/path/to/production';
} else {
  jsOutputDir = '/path/to/development';
  cssOutputDir = '/path/to/development';      
}

mix.js('resources/assets/js/xxxx.js', jsOutputDir)
   .css('resources/assets/css/xxxx.css',cssOutputdir)
```

now, run `npm run dev` or `npm run production`, your JavaScript and css files in different directory, good luck.

Answer (score -1):

this can be done actually without changing or adding new output directories. You can build your assets for development or production easily same as the old webpack. Eg:

```
//Run all mix in development
npm run dev

//Run mix in production
npm run production
```

`npm run production` will minify all your mix task and will be stored in public directory.

Please read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, It is not that I want to know. I **need** the development css will be in `/resources` and production css will be in `/public`. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, you can add a second parameter in your mix where you wanna specify each destinations.

Comment: It already added in `.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');` statement and, as I understand, output will be compiled in `public/css` in both `npm run dev` and `npm run production` cases. Where I can to define different output path for development build?

Comment: it should be 'resources/assets/css' as a second param.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to change it manually to  `public/assets/css` when I want to build the production bundle after development will be complete?